# Xpath to get value from a table

Tags: selenium, xpath, html-table

I am trying to get items and price values

```
Website: https://www.rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/

<div class="cart-info">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Items</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><strong>0</strong>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Price</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><strong>0</strong>
</td>
```

**What I have tried**:

```
.//*[@class='cart-info']//td/..//strong
```

**Problem:**
The locator above shows 2 of 2. Even when I try .//*[@class='cart-info']//td/..//strong[1] ,I still get 2 of 2. What can I change in my xpath so that I can locate that Item and Price individually ? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.

```
(.//*[@class='cart-info']//td/..//strong)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for items value:

```
//div[@class='cart-info']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/strong
```

and this for price value:

```
//div[@class='cart-info']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/strong
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete, another short options :

```
//tr[td[.="Items"]]//strong
//tr[td[.="Price"]]//strong
```